# pandas.read_sql with sqlite is extremly slow

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlite

I'm using pandas.read_sql with an sqlite Database and it is extremly slow. 
I have a table with 800 rows and 49 columns (dataype just TEXT and REAL) and it takes over 3 Minutes to fetch the data from database to the dataframe. 
The DB-File and the python script are running on the same machine and the same filesystem.

Is there any way to speed up pandas.read_sql?

This is the code fragment:

```
        self.logger.info('{} - START read_sql: {}'.format(table))
        result = pd.read_sql("select * from {}".format(table), self.dbconn,
                           index_col=indexcolname)
        self.logger.info('{} - END read_sql: {}'.format(table))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself:
The Problem was using the connection as instance attribut: self.dbconn
If i always initiate a new connection and close it at the end perfomance is absolutely no problem !

```
    conn = self.create_connection(self.db_file)

    self.logger.info('{} - START from sql: {}'.format(self.botid, table))
    Result = pd.read_sql("select * from {}".format(table), conn,
                           index_col=indexcolname)
    self.logger.info('{} - END from sql: {}'.format(self.botid, table))
    conn.close()
```